# Problem when inputing ivreg output into summary()

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, economics

I am using the command `ivreg` from the `AER` package. My data looks like this:

```
head(d0)

       y           x0       x1      x2       x3     x4        x5
1   0.005157174 18422880    0   four stars  GA  0.02857143  37963
2   0.005157174 18422880    0   four stars  GA  0.02857143  37963
3   0.008145795 18422880    0   two stars   GA  0.00993997  37963
4   0.004613947 22938495    0   four stars  GA  0.02857143  37963
5   0.005157174 18422880    0   four stars  GA  0.02857143  37963
6   0.008145795 18422880    0   three stars GA  0.00993997  37963
```

My `x0` variable is endogenous, so I would like to run the following regression, instrumenting `x0` with `x5` :

```
 mod_iv <- ivreg(y~x0+x1+x2+x3|x5+x1+x2+x3,data=d0)
```

The command above runs well. However, when I type `summary(mod_iv)`. I get the error message

```
Error in solve.default(vcov.hyp) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 9.79783e-23
```

It seems like this is common, as I found in [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-message-system-is-computationally-singular/72570). The interesting part is that it seems like the problem really is originated by `x0`. For instance, theis regression below **does run correctly** inside summary:

```
 mod_iv <- ivreg(y~x4+x1+x2+x3|x5+x1+x2+x3,data=d0)
 summary(mod_iv)
```

Do you know what could be causing this error?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068583/system-is-computationally-singular-error-from-linearhypothesis-but-the-matrix-ha)